# VBA loop conditional stops being evaluated after arbitrary number of lines

Tags: vba, loops, excel, for-loop, while-loop

Here is my code. The code itself seems to work but for some reason the conditional statement stops after line 32645. I tried switching all variables to Long, didn't help.

Also, the code works if I make it start at line 32646, but then stops at a random later line (~18000). There seem to be no similarities in the data it stops at. Originally I tried a for loop specifying the start and end row but that didn't work either so I tried the while loop (both theoretically should work but neither seems to ).

It needs to be able to process 130,000 + lines, any idea why this might be happening ?

**The Problem**

The loop stops running without error and by adding a messagebox I know my row incrementing variable ends up at the last row, but depending on the workbook, the conditional statements stop being evaluated after an arbitrary number of lines.

If I run the script starting at the line below where the first run stopped, it works but again for a (possibly different) arbitrary number of steps.

*Notes*

I have made all my variables "Long" type. I used Option Explicit.

```
data_row = CLng(InputBox("Please enter the row number of the first data entry"))
Worksheets.Add(After:=Worksheets(1)).name = "Formatted_Output"

Set ws = Sheets("Formatted_Output")
Worksheets(1).Activate
LastCol = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Columns(ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Columns.Count).Column
LastRow = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows(ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count).row
data_col = LastCol

 'loop through entries to get account and permissions
 increment = data_row
 Do Until increment = LastRow
    If Cells(data_row, data_col) = "" Then
        data_col = data_col - 1
    Else
   ' ~> For illegal ==> access denied permission that throws errors
        If Cells(data_row, data_col).Value = "==>access denied" Then
            permissions = "access denied" 'remove illegal =
            ws.Cells(output_row, 3).Value = permissions 'print permissions to output file
        Else
            permissions = Cells(data_row, data_col).Value 'cell should be permission cell of each row
            ws.Cells(output_row, 3).Value = permissions 'print permissions to output file
        End If

        data_col = data_col - 1 'domain / account cell is now highlighted

        If InStrRev(Cells(data_row, data_col).Value, "?") > 0 Then

            account = Split(Cells(data_row, data_col).Value, "?")(1) & Str(unknown_count) ' separate domain name and unknown id
            unknown_count = unknown_count + 1 ' counting the number of unkown accounts found
            ws.Cells(output_row, 2) = account 'print unknown account Id to output

            domain_bit = Split(Cells(data_row, data_col).Value, "?")(0) '' get separate domain name from id cell
            data_col = data_col - 1 'domain second from end cell is now highlighted

            Do While data_col > 0 'generate domain from rest of row
                domain_bit = Cells(data_row, data_col).Value & domain_bit 'domain built backwards
                data_col = data_col - 1 'check next column for more of location name
            Loop

            ws.Cells(output_row, 1) = domain_bit
                'data_col = LastCol
                'data_row = data_row + 1
                'output_row = output_row + 1

        ElseIf InStrRev(Cells(data_row, data_col).Value, "\") > 0 Then

            account = Split(Cells(data_row, data_col).Value, "\")(1) 'separate account ID
            ws.Cells(output_row, 2) = account 'print account ID to oputput

            domain_bit = Split(Cells(data_row, data_col).Value, "\")(0)
            data_col = data_col - 1 'domain second from end cell is now highlighted

            Do While data_col > 0 'generate domain from rest of row
                domain_bit = Cells(data_row, data_col).Value & domain_bit 'domain built backwards
                data_col = data_col - 1 'check next column for more of location name
            Loop

            ws.Cells(output_row, 1) = domain_bit 'output to file

        Else
                         account = Cells(data_row, data_col).Value 'account is just whole cell whether empty or one word no path
            ws.Cells(output_row, 2) = account 'print account ID to oputput

            data_col = data_col - 1 'domain second from end cell is now highlighted (since no domain in account cell)
            Do While data_col > 0 'generate domain from rest of row
                domain_bit = Cells(data_row, data_col).Value & domain_bit 'domain built backwards
                data_col = data_col - 1 'check next column for more of location name
            Loop

            ws.Cells(output_row, 1) = domain_bit 'output to file
        End If

    data_col = LastCol
    data_row = data_row + 1
    output_row = output_row + 1
    End If

'Next increment
ws.Range("E" & 1) = unknown_count
increment = increment + 1

If increment = LastRow Then
    MsgBox (Str(increment) & "=" & Str(LastRow))
End If

Loop
```

Comment: 32646 would be right on the 2^15 boundary, e.g. a signed 16bit int. you may have missed a 'long' definition somewhere, so you're still dealing with 16bit ints at some point, instead of logs throughout.

Comment: Simple question - This seems very close to the upper limit for an `Integer` data type - Have you defined ALL your counters as `Long`?? That may be your issue...

Comment: Hi, thanks for commenting. I defined every single number as Long. Ctrl-F Integer and there are no results anymore. That is the confusing part since I figured that must have been the problem.

Comment: Do you use `Option Explicit` at the top of your code module? It will force you to explicitly declare every single variable used. If you do not use it, VBA will still accept any undeclared or misspelled variables.

Comment: I didn't before- just added it but all the variables had been correctly assigned.

Comment: On which line of code do you get the error?

Comment: No error, the run "finishes" but doesn't actually evaluate the conditional statements for the next 100,000 lines.
However, if I try printing something random on every line, it works so each row is being actually reached in the loop.

Comment: I notice that you are somewhat inconsistent in your assignment of values to cells, sometimes using .Value and sometimes not? May not be the source of your problem. I've seen this kind of mysterious loop behavior when Excel gets "confused" about what sheet it is working in - cure is to fully qualify range references. Another possibility is that the nature of your data changes, and you newly enter one of your conditionals, with unexpected results. Would be easier to investigate with a sample of your data. (BTW, have you stepped through your code with the debugger?)

Comment: As chuff said, debug from line 32645. Please keep us posted if you find issue. GL!

Comment: Do you have any `On Error Resume Next` statements which are letting errors through undetected?

Comment: can you share your workbook?

Comment: No 'code'On Error Resume Next'code' statements. 
Tried consistency in adding 'code'.Value'code' but it hasn't worked. 
Unfortunately, I can't share the workbook for confidentiality reasons but coulmns go: 
column 1: domain path  | column 2 either domain\id or domain | col 3 either domain\id or permissions 
Rightmost column is always some permission string then the column left ot thet either a plain text string or a domain name\id and all preceeding columns in a row specify domain paths.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your first overarching if statement is not doing as it should, this being if it is found to be true the `data_row` variable is not increased disabling an automatic row increase.

If this is what you wanted then the `increment` variable needs to be moved inside the if statement as it increases irrespective of the `data_row` variable.

I think a `for-next` would be better:

```
for data_row = 1 to LastRow
    'do some stuff
next
```

This will cycle through all rows 1 to `LastRow` for every iteration.

---

**Added better answer:**

```
Do Until increment > LastRow
    ...
    data_col = LastCol
    data_row = data_row + 1
    output_row = output_row + 1
    increment = increment + 1
    End If

    If increment > LastRow Then
        MsgBox (Str(increment) & ">" & Str(LastRow))
    End If
Loop
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment, however the first if statement tries to find where the data starts on that particular row (every row has data, not all have same number of columns.  
  
After data is found then the else manipulates it based on the nested conditions. Hence, i only increment after the else is evaluated.

Comment: But you don't by where you placed the `increment + 1` variable. Place it below the `data_Row + 1`.

Comment: With every blank last column the variable `increment` gets closer to the `LastRow` variable without actually analysing the row.

Comment: I see ! I will be able to test this in about an hour from now. Hopefully it works! Will keep you posted.

Comment: I've added a better code snippet for a guide as to what I would try to change. Good luck.

Comment: It works ! Thank you so much. It also helped me to find another flaw in my logic too so I am doubly grateful.